# How do I request the server to add an item to a collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am having issues trying to get custom POST requests to work.

I have tried a couple of possible solutions so far, e.g. messing around with the routing, using forms and asp tag helpers, etc, but I have not been able to pinpoint the issue.

Referring the code attached below, on submitting the form I am expecting that the OnPostAdd method will be called with appropriate To and From values provided as inputs. However, the page just redirects to "./ContextFreeGrammar/Add" without executing a post request.

OnGet() and OnPost() works in this page model but how do I get AddRule(Rule rule) to be called?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Earley_Parser.Language;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Storyteller.Pages.EarleyParser {
    public class ContextFreeGrammarModel : PageModel {
        public readonly Grammar_2 _grammarContext;

        public ContextFreeGrammarModel(IGrammar grammarContext) {
            _grammarContext = (Grammar_2) grammarContext;

            _grammarContext.Add("", "S");
            _grammarContext.Add("A", "S");
            _grammarContext.Add("AA", "A");
            _grammarContext.Add("a", "A");
        }

        // POST: Default/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult OnPostAdd(String to, String from) {
            try {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                _grammarContext.Add(to, from);

                return RedirectToPage();
            } catch {
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // POST: Default/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult OnPostDelete(Int32 id) {
            try {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                _grammarContext.Remove(_grammarContext.ElementAt(id));

                return RedirectToPage();
            } catch {
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@page
@model Storyteller.Pages.EarleyParser.ContextFreeGrammarModel

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // jQuery methods go here...
            $("#F").keyup(function () {
                if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
                    $("#T").focus();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<div>
    <form asp-action="add" method="post">
        <table id="grammarRuleTable" class="table">
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var rule in Model._grammarContext) {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center" class="oneCharacterWideColumn">
                            @(new String(rule.f))
                        </td>
                        <td class="oneCharacterWideColumn">
                            →
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin:0">
                            @(new String(rule.t))
                        </td>
                        <td class="oneCharacterWideColumn">
                            <button onclick="myFunction()">
                                <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                <tr>
                    <td class="oneCharacterWideColumn">
                        <input id="F" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" style="text-align:center"
                               asp-route-to="from" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="oneCharacterWideColumn" width="">
                        →
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="T" type="text" maxlength="128" style="width:100%"
                               asp-route-to="to" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="oneCharacterWideColumn"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by './ContextFreeGrammar/Add'? We cannot find that route in your code above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with handlers.

```
public IActionResult OnPostAdd(String to, String from) {
    try {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        _grammarContext.Add(to, from);

        return RedirectToPage();
    } catch {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

-

```
<form asp-page-handler="Add" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Grammar</button>
    <input id="handler_parameter_from" type="hidden" name="from" value="hello"/>
    <input id="handler_parameter_to" type="hidden" name="to" value="world"/>
</form>
```

Do notice the name OnPost**Handler** or OnPost**Handler**Async.

You can even use [Multiple handlers per page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page)

Comment: Thank you so much! Replacing asp-action="add" with asp-page-handler="Add" solved this issue.